# Saying a pointer is equal to a position in the memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, vector

I have a *very* simple code here but I can't really understand what's happening on the memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int v[8], *u = &v[2];
    v[2] = 20;
    printf("%d",*u);

    return 0;
}
```

So basically, when I ask it to print *u, it will give me 20. I can't understand why. I'm new to pointers and I never saw a example where you're giving a value to a *pointer.

I can only make simple codes like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int a = 10, *b;
    b = &a;
    printf("%d",*b);

return 0;
}
```

Which I can easily understand what's happening. Can someone make a comparison on what's happening in the memory on these two cases?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int v[8], *u = &v[2];
```

This line is defining two things. It's making an array of ints called `v` that has storage for 8 ints. It's also making a pointer to int, called `u` that is set to point to the second element in `v`.

```
v[2] = 20;
```

This line sets the second element in the `v` array to 20. Keep in mind that `u` also points to this element from the previous line.

```
printf("%d",*u);
```

This line just prints the value that `u` points to. Since it points to the second element in the array `v`, and that element is set to 20, it'll print 20.

Your second code:

```
int a = 10, *b;
b = &a;
printf("%d",*b);
```

Could also be written as:

```
int a = 10, *b = &a;
printf("%d",*b);
```

It's just moving the second line onto the first. Then the only difference between your two examples is the array notation.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the second one could be written like that as well, but wasn't really grasping the concept behind it. Thank you!

Comment: Note: it's not the **SECOND** element it's the **THIRD**.

Comment: You mean 0-th, 1-st ... yes of course! But I always fear non-experts to think it's actually the second position in the array.

Comment: lifts do that in some countries... ground floor, first floor, second floor

Comment: @M.M Good example, in my country it's that way. I never thought about the ground floor numerically but it's the 0-th floor indeed.

Comment: @M.M Then why does sekimm2 say: *It's just moving the second line onto the first.* where there are only two lines. And he says: *Your second code:* where there are only two code examples. Let's face it, he made a mistake.

Comment: @M.M - in the land of C, the array element with index zero is described as the first.  So an index of `2` corresponds to the third element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about the meaning of the `*` which depends on the context, in

```
int *u;
```

it means that we declared `u` as a pointer of `int`, but in

```
*u = 1;
```

it dereferences `u` and assigns `1` to the first element `u` points at.

So writing

```
int *u = 1;
```

is surely confusing, but in this case you are declaring `u` as a pointer and initializing it with a `1` (*which is an arbitrary value and this code would lead to undefined behavior*), it's actually equivalent to

```
int *u;
u = 1;
```

In general, (*though it's simply my opinion*) I like to separate initializations from declarations everywhere and actually only declare variables at the beginning of a code block. Because it makes the code easier to read.

But in all fairness, experienced programmers would never find this confusing so it's ok if you write ugly code where you declare variables whenever they need to appear.